# Hide/Show Object in Excel without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2016

Due to workplace restrictions, I am unable to use macros/VBA in Excel. I was wondering if there was a way to show or hide previously created graphs based on the value in a cell without using VBA. I currently have it set up as a picture, but was hoping there was a more effective way, as this makes it difficult to change aspects of the graph.

Thanks,

Comment: *Due to workplace restrictions...* when will they [workplaces] learn how stupid this is?

Answer (score 0):

Move all your Charts to a worksheet or set of worksheets that you can manually hide.

Comment: I'm creating a summary tab to display a user selected chart so users can easily review the status of the project. I don't need the worksheet hidden, I need certain charts to display based on which one the user wishes to view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I would look up different ranges based on what is selected, by using OFFSET.

Set up your graphs and put a column full of `=NA()` next to them. (The reason I use =NA() and not blanks is because Excel will plot blanks as 0, but won't plot #N/A at all.) Now point your graphs to a separate set of cells that reference either the blank column or true data depending on what you have picked.

So my data columns look like:

```
      A                B            C            D                    E
1     OFFSET values:   0            1            Graph to choose:     1
2     x-values         Blank graph  Actual 
3            1                =na()        4
4            2                =na()        6
5            3                =na()        8
```

and I point my graph at the following cells:

```
x-values  y-values
1         =offset(B3,0,E2)
2         =offset(B4,0,E2)
3         =offset(B5,0,E2)
```

Hopefully the picture below makes it clearer

[image: excel example]

Comment: Thank you. While this would work in theory, because of the complexity of the data and the graphs (clustered, stacked graph by month with cumulative and forecasted cumulative expenses for 7 different expense categories shown in different combinations), the OFFSET and related equations would become unmanageable.

Answer (score 0):

From the Selection Pane, click on the little eyeball icon when you have selected the chart manually. This at least allows you to preserve it as a *Chart* and not a picture.

[image]

I'm not aware of any way to make this dynamic based on a cell reference. There's only so much you can do without event-handling which would require VBA, and there is no built-in formula or command which would alter the visibility/display of a chart.

Comment: I figured as much. Thank you for your help.